# Download files on emulator

Tags: android, download

I've just downloaded this example http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html. It doesn't work on emulator, but it works on my android device.
I've got internet connection on emulator. Browser works.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to clarify "doesn't work." If you're using the emulator, you probably have the SDK and the other tools, open up logcat and see what the error message, if any, is. ("adb -e logcat")

Answer (score 1):

There's a blog post on how to run Google Play on an emulator and pretend to be any device. Might want to check it out:
https://apkudo.com/?p=510